# How can I search for a substring that is between two values ​of a string in python?

Tags: python

someone who can give me an idea about doing the following: I have a text file
of a single line but they send me several data, all as if it were xml but within a txt.
ej:

```
<Respuesta><ResultEnviado><Resultado><Entrega>00123</Entrega><Refer>MueblesHiroshima</Refer><Item>34</Item><Valor>780</Valor></Resultado></ResultEnviado><EntregaItemResulados><EntregaItem><ItemId>123</ItemId><NameItem>MuebleSala</NameItem><ValorItem>180</ValorItem></EntregaItem><EntregaItem><ItemId>124</ItemId><NameItem>MuebleComedor</NameItem>ValorItem>200</ValorItem></EntregaItem><EntregaItem><ItemId>125</ItemId><NameItem>Cama</NameItem>ValorItem>200</ValorItem></EntregaItem><EntregaItem><ItemId>126</ItemId><NameItem>escritorio</NameItem>ValorItem>200</ValorItem></EntregaItem></EntregaItemResulados></Respuesta>
```

As you could see, it is a file with the extension txt.

```
<ResultEnviado><Resultado><Entrega>1213255654</Entrega><Refer>MueblesHiroshima</Refer><Item>34</Item><Valor>780</Valor></Resultado></ResultEnviado>
```

I am using python for the exercise.

Thank you very much for your comments or ideas.

Comment: What would the output look like for that example? try using [this beautifier](https://jsonformatter.org/xml-formatter) before you answer

Comment: check out if this helps solve your problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69452755/how-to-parse-xml-from-string-in-python

Comment: <Respuesta>
 <ResultEnviado>
  <Resultado>
   <Entrega>0000123</Entrega>
   <Refer>Muebleria Palito</Refer>
   <Item>34</Item>
   <Valor>780</Valor>
  </Resultado>
 </ResultEnviado>
 <EntregaItemResulados>
  <EntregaItem>
   <ItemId>123</ItemId>
   <NameItem>MuebleSala</NameItem>
   <ValorItem>180</ValorItem>
  </EntregaItem>
  <EntregaItem>
   <ItemId>124</ItemId>
   <NameItem>MuebleComedor</NameItem>
   <ValorItem>600</ValorItem>
  </EntregaItem>
 </EntregaItemResulados>
</Respuesta>

Comment: Relevant information belongs in the question itself (you can edit it in) rather than in a comment. In any event -- that looks more like input than expected output.

Comment: the output would be like this: <Resultado><Entrega>0000123</Entrega><Refer>Muebleria Palito</Refer><Item>34</Item><Valor>780</Valor></Resultado>

Comment: is what is between the value ResultEnviado

Comment: What do you want the end result of the program to print? Is it the number series that is between all the text so it would print this `1213255654` ? Or do you want everything between the `<Resultado>` tags?

Comment: Or do you want everything between the <Resultado>  . This

Answer (score 1):

Here we can use regular expressions `.search()` and `.match()` functions to find everything between the set tags. Note you need to import regular expression using the `import re`.

More info on regular expressions in python: [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

```python
import re

#open the file and read it
path = "C:/temp/file.txt"
with open(path, "r") as f:
    text = f.read()

#we use regular experssion to find everything between the tags
match = re.search("<ResultEnviado>(.*?)</ResultEnviado>", text)

#prints the text if it matches
if match:
    print(match.group(1))
else:
    print("No match found.")
```

this prints:

`<Resultado><Entrega>00123</Entrega><Refer>MueblesHiroshima</Refer><Item>34</Item><Valor>780</Valor></Resultado>`

Please let me know if you need any more help.

Comment: Thanks my friend, I came out with your program. I'm going to implement it